# SQL Server WHERE clause based on conditions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have a SQL Server query that I want to add `where` clause for `@catid`, `@factor`, and `@title1` if each of them are not null or zero.

Don't want to make my code messy. For example if `@catid` is null, condition `catid=@catid` will be omitted from where and results like :

```
where catid = @catid 
  and factorid = @factor 
  and description = @title1
```

And so for other `@factor` and `@title1` parameters.

Any idea?

This is the main code:

```
select @countoffset = count(*) 
from acchesab ac
inner join accusrhesab ach on ac.accid = ach.id
inner join accdoc acd on acd.id = ac.docid
where catid = @catid 
  and factorid = @factor 
  and description = @title1
```

Comment: You may want to read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below script. This will check the value is column Either NULL or equal to Provided value. Both case it will return TRUE.

```
select @countoffset=count(*) from acchesab ac
inner join accusrhesab ach on ac.accid=ach.id
inner join accdoc acd on acd.id=ac.docid
where 
(catid=@catid OR catid IS NULL)  
and (factorid=@factor OR factorid IS NULL) 
and (description=@title1 OR description IS NULL)
```